# How to extract domains with/without whois from com zone file of verisign?

Tags: dns

I have downloaded the `.com` zonefile. It is more than 11GB after unzipping. I want to extract domains with whois if possible.

How to make that happen?

Comment: I hope this question should be asked on the [Webmasters community](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What did you try? With any programming language you can do a loop on the content and do a whois query for each domain. OF course this will be hugely underperforming you will hit the registry whois rate limiting etc. So your question is too broad.

Comment: First I want to extract domains from zonefile. I tried with python and ruby but facing issues. Need some guide from scratch in python, php or ruby.

Comment: I got an option to extract from python using https://github.com/ambelovsky/py-verisigntld-to-mongodb which helped me in extracting but it takes more than 8hrs to complete. Is there any other way to make this process fast?